# uitextview font not changing with fontWIthName

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uitextview

I'm trying to change the font for a UITextView with textview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:etc];
But for some reason it isn't doing anything and it always displays the same font and size.
Here's the code:

```
UITextView *descriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
descriptionTextView.editable = NO;
descriptionTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
descriptionTextView.text = description;
titleTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Veranda" size:17.0]; //<- this line isn't working
[cell.contentView addSubview:descriptionTextView];
```

Any idea what the probem might be?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

May be the error in that you change font of other text field?
You operate with textview named 'descriptionTextView', but change font of 'titleTextView'

Or that default font is named "Verdana", not "Veranda"

Comment: *facepalm* thanks Mikhail you were right - I changed it to what it is and now it works

Comment: @leksah255 Accept answer if it's right, as this helps others too to refer!